# How to get number of rows in a LabelBox Dataset?

Tags: python

Is there a quick way to retrieve the length of a Dataset using the LabelBox Python API? The best I've come up with so far is:

```
len(list(dataset.data_rows()))
```

This fetches the data for each row from the table, which is clearly not ideal and very slow. The docs explicitly discourage using `list` too, however I have not found any alternatives that do not require iterating over the whole Dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to find the number of data rows in a dataset would be to use the `row_count` field on a dataset object, as shown here:

```
# Grab the dataset
dataset = client.get_dataset("<DATASET_ID>")

# Print the count of data rows
print(dataset.row_count)
```

I've included this answer on Labelbox's new Community page, which you can reach [here](https://community.labelbox.com/t/find-the-number-of-data-rows-in-a-dataset/70). Thanks for posing this question -- please don't hesitate to post other questions or share an interesting discoveries to the Community page. We'd love to see the Community page evolve into a thriving forum for Labelboxers!